# Fixing the eyes

Tags: modeling

So anyway, this is my first model and I'm currently working on the eyes. Yet I've been having a problem.

When I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to invert the gray part, the white parts invert themselves instead. Is there anyway to fix this? Please help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWo4s.jpg

[image]

Comment: Do that while only that face is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, while in *Edit Mode*, tap <kbd>A</kbd> to deselect everything, 
then tap <kbd>C</kbd>, so you can color in the areas you want to select. (Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking to deselect, if need be.)

<kbd>Right Click</kbd> to exit *Circle Select* mode.

Simply select the area you wish to flip normals on,
then do your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> trick.